laravel anchor tag href and value are different
Anyone who experience this issue with anchor tags at laravel , I encounter an issue which href shows correct url href="job but the properties value shows = jobs/jobs. I don't have any issue with this anchor tags when I'm in different routes.
I used this route
Route::get('/jobs/{id}', function ($id)  {
    $job = Job::find($id);
    return view('job',['job'=>$job]);
});

enter image description here
enter image description here
I try to look for any similar issue here but I found nothing. the anchor tag is reusable , I did used a static anchor tag but both shows values /jobs/jobs but the href is /jobs only
@props(['active' => false])
<a  class="{{ $active ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white' }} rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium" 
aria-current="{{ $active ? 'page' : 'false' }}"
{{ $attributes }}
>{{$slot}} </a>


What is $attributes? Give us controller codes...

it is a reserve word to get the properties of a tag and pass it to another. I haven't use controller.

I don't know if this is how you solved this but I try to changed the href=""
to {{ url(name_path) }}

I figure it out now, never forgot to include in the beginning the " / " of href
href="/about"

If you're using a reusable Blade component for your anchor tags, ensure that the href attribute is being set correctly.
@props(['active' => false, 'href'])

<a href="{{ $href }}" class="{{ $active ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white' }} rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium" aria-current="{{ $active ? 'page' : 'false' }}">
{{ $slot }}
</a>

Or Add some debugging statements to check the values being passed to your Blade component.
{{-- Debugging --}}
<pre>{{ $href }}</pre>

